# YOLOv5x-cls load from torch.hub not working

Tags: pytorch, yolov5

I am trying to load a pretrained YOLOv5 image classifier:

```
torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5l-cls', pretrained=True)
```

But got `RuntimeError: Cannot find callable yolov5l-cls in hubconf`. Same thing with 5x,5s,5n. Any clues why? Thanks and Regards,